# What is the word for using one word to replace another for cosmetic reasons?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm sure this is a dumb question, but I am having a total mental block.

Is there a word for when you alter the verbal description of something in order to make it appear better? I'm thinking about something along the lines of "Despite the ____ changes to the law, nothing really changed".

I don't think cosmetic works, but that's all I can come up with.

Comment: _cosmetic_ is perfectly ok with a tweak of the example sentence: the  changes of the law were _cosmetic_.

Comment: Consider _ornamentation_.

Answer (score 25):

"Despite the [**superficial**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/superficial) changes," works well in this context.  Two related definitions from Oxford: "Existing or occurring at or on the surface," and "Appearing to be true or real only until examined more closely."

To insinuate that the revision is a pretext, the **ostensible** or **so-called** changes.  Also disparaging, but without the implication of dishonesty: **trivial**, **unimportant** or **desultory**¹.  If you approve of them, **stylistic** changes make something sound better and **clarifying** revisions (or, more commonly, clarifications) make it clearer, without altering the meaning.  Some more neutral options include **minor**, **incidental**, **inconsequential** and **negligible**.

¹ Which have different shades of meaning: *trivial* changes don't affect anything because they're so minor, *unimportant* ones changed something that doesn't matter, and *desultory* ones have no focus or purpose.

Comment: '[Desultory](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/51148)' is the adjectival form of a Latin word for a performer who jumps around horses. It's about conversation that skips around, not a superficial or trivial one.

Comment: @lly *Desultory* has several other meanings, including: lack of purpose, lack of connection to the main subject, and disappointing in quality. The second is more what I had in mind, with shades of the other two. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desultory

Comment: @lly A couple of examples of similar real-world usage: "The House budget resolution recommends a number of desultory changes to the Pell Grant and student loan programs, most of which have been featured in recent years' budgets as well." "The Reds fell to the absolute bottom of the Western Division for the next few years, losing Seaver after the 1982 season. A series of desultory changes were made [....]" "That truth is apparent from the desultory changes made in an effort to make things more interesting [....]"

Comment: Those uses don't mean what you think they do. They state the changes were 'all over the place' and thus ineffective, not 'trivial' or 'unimportant'. Scroll down to the part where it says 'Did you know...'

Comment: @lly Please see my earlier comment. That's what I said desultory meant. It makes sense to say, "Despite the desultory changes to the law, nothing really changed," and this usage is disparaging. This is not synonymous with many other words I listed. For example, "stylistic changes" has a different meaning too.

Comment: @lly I've added a footnote that not all the words I listed were synonyms.

Answer (score 19):

Cosmetic is fine. It's often used in this way, **cosmetic changes**: changes that may appear interesting but lack substance. Another term is **aesthetic changes**: changes in appearance, perception. Another relevant expression is **lipstick on a pig**: when one tries to make something ugly appear nice by some superficial measure, but obviously without success.

P.S. I agree with Davislor that words like *superficial* and *inconsequential* are good words to describe changes that don't really change much; but those words don't capture the question's desire for a word to describe changes that make it "appear better". Even so, they may fit the desired context.

Comment: Do you really need prompting for substantiating references after all this time?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Do you really need to prompt people after all this time?

Comment: Apparently. Some people don't seem to care about the standards of quality I believe (and certainly hope) ELU still expects.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't believe it has ever been the way you might want it to be. It's not an academic publication (although even in academic pblications references aren't needed when something is common knowledge in the field; some academics over-reference). People use references where they feel they're necessary.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Being a native speaker of the language is reference enough.

Comment: @jamesqf Try getting onto an English course at university with that attitude. And note that ELU actually states that corroborating references are almost mandatory.

Comment: Being a native speaker certainly isn't sufficient to justify a word choice, as most educated native speakers of any language are well aware. There's more than enough wrong common knowledge and falsehoods to trip up someone who's not careful to check their knowledge - in which case being native speaker is irrelevant because the check source can be provided anyway.

Comment: @jamesqf do you know for a fact that Cerberus is a native speaker?  Is being a native speaker sufficient proof that they know what they are talking about? Always? N.B. I have nothing, absolutely nothing, against this answer and the fact it is not "supported" by references.

Comment: What word is to good-looking as *euphonious* is to good-sounding? And no, you aren’t allowed to combine Greek *εὐ‑* with Latin *video* — for despite other arguments barring such hybrid miscegenations, that one would result in a compound where it would be too hard to figure out how to handle with respect to its colliding v’s.

Comment: +1 for * aesthetic* - It was my immediate thought as a solution to the OP's question and I was going to post that as an answer myself. Maybe you should consider highlighting it more than it already is (**bold**?) - As there are a lot of answers to wade through, I only found it by using my browser's search tool.

Comment: @tchrist Well, you could say *euoptic* as a neologism, from *euoptos* "good looking". Do you think I should add that?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I certainly care about quality. But I don't much care for petty dictators, which is why I don't bother to come here very often.

Comment: @alephzero Are you describing the people who decided on the rules and standards, or the people who (in accordance with ELU principles) try to maintain the quality intended to be achieved by those rules and standards, as 'petty dictators'? I'd say either smacks of subversion. There are many other English language websites where answers are hardly convincing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: You think everyone has always agreed with you on this point, but I don't believe that is the case at all. Just look at a couple of our most highly upvoted answers. I consider it your personal wish and interpretation, which are duly noted. Don't you think your comments are creating more problems than they could ever solve? Is all this strife and negativity towards newcomers worth the infinitesimal chance that I or others might comply with your wishes? Would it perhaps be a good idea to open a special chat room about this issue that you can refer people to instead?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: What does an English course at university have to do with language use?  I was required to take several such courses, but I don't recall ever having been asked to supply references for word choices.  Indeed, what would such references look like?  As far as I can see, just an instance of some other English speaker (Shakespeare, say) having previously used the word.

Comment: Why should your answer be considered more accurate than OP's "I don't think 'cosmetic' works, but that's all I can come up with"? (Though admittedly both show the same level of research.) And if OP is incorrect, how does one justify 8 upvotes? I'd **love** to be able to just treat ELU as an interesting and often informative chatroom, but without reasonable regulations it becomes a mere opinion-posting site. And I believe it was intended to be a comprehensive and authoritative repository of knowledge about the English language.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I think your intention is good, but I don't agree with you at all on this point, nor about your approach of scolding people.

Comment: I've others, but 'Hi! What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer; one that you can support with authoritative references.... Edit your [ answer] and put in your support; then we'll be able to [upvote].' – Matt Gutting;  'A good answer is comprehensive and contains evidence showing why it is correct. Links to external resources are encouraged. Answers which consist of virtually nothing but an unsupported statement or a citation are not useful and may be subject to deletion – even correct answers. For help writing a ...

Comment: good answer, see [Answer].' – MετάEd and 'SE requires that any assertions that aren't self-evident be backed up with some kind of reference or sufficiently demonstrative example - Otherwise, the correctness of your answers will only be apparent to people who know the correct answers already, rather than to people who would actually benefit from some instruction.' – user867 spell out site requirements pretty clearly.

Answer (score 8):

*"Despite the ____ changes of the law, nothing really changed"*

The sense of the sentence with the term *cosmetic* diminishes the severity of the change, and when it is used with *despite*,  it contradicts and renders somewhat meaningless. The same I doubt with the word *nominal*, if it is used with *despite*.

**[Nominal](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ucweb-b-bookmark&oq=nominal%20mea&aqs=mobile-gws-lite.0.0l5&q=nominal%20meaning)**

*existing in name only.*

Answer (score 6):

**Cosmetic** fits the example sentence you give as a direct drop-in word, but it doesn't fit the description of your question or the second sentence in your question.

In other words, because of the way you've phrased your question, it's asking for something a bit different.

What is a word for using one word to replace another cosmetically?

[**Rephrasing**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rephrasing):

> to phrase or express (something) in a different way especially to make the meaning clearer · Let me rephrase the question.

Editors often use the word [**recasting**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recasting) for this purpose, one definition of which is simply "to present (something) in a different way."

Both of those words could actually suit your sentence if the sentence itself were changed slightly:

> Despite the rephrasing of the law, nothing really changed.

In fact, using *rephrasing* (or *recasting*) in this slightly changed sentence would help with the use of *despite* (as mentioned in another answer).

Of course, you *can* change the meaning of something by rephrasing it significantly enough, but cosmetic changes are certainly not excluded.

More informally, there is another word that can imply minor (cosmetic) rephrasing of writing.

[**Tweaks**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tweaks):

> a small change or adjustment · We made a few *tweaks* to the original recipe.

So:

> Despite the tweaks to the law, nothing really changed.

Answer (score 6):

I find the question somewhat unclear. 
Based on the title and the second sentence,
it seems like you might be looking for ***euphemism*** (or ***euphemistic***):

> [English Oxford (living) Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/euphemism):
>
>   A mild or indirect word or expression
>     substituted for one considered to be too harsh or blunt
>     when referring to something unpleasant or embarrassing.
>   *‘“downsizing” as a euphemism for cuts’*
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=euphemism):
>
>   A mild, indirect, or vague term
>     for one that is considered harsh, blunt, or offensive: “Euphemisms such as ‘slumber room’ ... abound in the funeral business” 
>     (Jessica Mitford).
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/euphemism):
>
>   A euphemism is a polite word or expression that is used to refer to things
>     which people may find upsetting or embarrassing to talk about,
>     for example sex, the human body, or death.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use the preposition *despite*, then I don't think it makes sense to use anything meaning *cosmetic*.  This is because *nothing really changed* is exactly what one would expect as a consequence of cosmetic changes, not *despite* them.

It would make more sense to say "Despite the formal changes in the law, nothing really changed."  This would imply that, whatever changes were made, they must have been cosmetic since they changed nothing.

*Formal* here entails any degree of change.

Comment: You make a good point that *despite* is a negative polarity term (the down-vote on your answer isn't mine). However, even *cosmetic* changes are changes, and *despite* can still be used in the usual sense. Compare with the positive polarity phrasing: "[ * ] *Because of the cosmetic changes, nothing really changed.*" This is because the important bits are "*Despite ... changes ... nothing changed*". Changing the phrasing can admit neutral and positive forms: "*The changes were cosmetic. Nothing really changed.*" or "*Because the changes were cosmetic, nothing really changed.*".

Answer (score 4):

> Despite the ***apparent***  changes of the law, nothing really changed

ODO:

> **[apparent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apparent)**
>
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **2** Seeming real or true, but not necessarily so.
>
> ‘True, the apparent freedom and rationality of the human will may
>   prove an illusion.’
>
> ‘We all end up paying more to avoid a problem which is normally more
>   apparent than real.’

Answer (score 1):

The noun answer to your headline question is **euphemism**.

## The adjective you're looking for in your example sentence is *anything* meaning '[of minor importance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Thesaurus:insignificant)' or '[in appearance, name, or thought](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/supposed) [only]'.

**There are *dozens* of those in English**. [Your original '**cosmetic**' is the second one](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/450690/171986). [Davislor mentions '**trivial**', '**unimportant**', '**minor**', '**incidental**', '**inconsequential**', '**negligible**' for the first and '**superficial**' and '**ostensible**' for the second](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/450701/171986). [Mr Koya's '**nominal**' is the second](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/450707/171986) and can appear as 'in name only' as a prep. phrase. [Alwayslearning's '**apparent**' is the second](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/450699/171986), as is [Hyperpallium's '**purported**'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/450727/171986).

**Some that haven't been mentioned**:

- **frivolous** or **silly** changes don't take the issue seriously;
- **petty** changes are the same with more condescension;
- **inconsiderable**, **minor**, **meager**, **paltry**, **piddly**, **pitiful**, or **trifling** changes don't go remotely far enough;
- **insignificant**, **ignorable**, **minimal**, or **worthless** changes do hardly anything at all;
- **notional** or **putative** changes exist on paper and in argument but do sod-all in actuality;
- **so-called**, **supposed**, **alleged**, **assumed**, or **reputed** changes are being proclaimed or imagined as 'change' by someone... but that someone is misinformed or being deceitful;
- the words '**hypothetical**' or '**theoretical**' acknowledge that it all worked fine as a thought-experiment but imply that things didn't go as planned.

Answer (score 0):

> in order to make it appear better

I think something based on the verb **embellish** would address this part of your question. It means:

> to make something more beautiful by adding something to it ([cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/embellish))

So you can say:

Despite the embellishing modifications to the law, nothing really changed.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your exact needs, consider **machinations**. As in "Despite the machinations to the law, nothing really changed."

> 1 : an act of machinating
>      2 : a scheming or crafty action or artful design intended to accomplish some usually evil end backstage
>   machinations … that have dominated the film industry —Peter
>   Bogdanovich

"Machination." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 17 June 2018.

Another possibility is **purported**. "Despite the purported changes to the law, nothing (has) really changed". This is useful if you are wanting to push back against how the change was portrayed by those announcing it or reporting on it.

Both of these options serve to introduce an anonymous person or group that are responsible for the change, or for characterizing the change, but retain focus on the change itself. Indictments against the changes tend to filter back to the machinators or purporters by implication..

Comment: 'Machinations to the law' wouldn't really work, let alone that nothing changed *despite* them. That said, there are rephrasings of the original that could be made to work with it, so long as one wished to imply that a sinister cabal was responsible for the failure of progress on the underlying issue.

Comment: Re. machinations, the evil cabal bit is possible, but entirely optional. It could also just refer to some apparachik trying to clear their in-basket.